# No such module 'Segment'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, segment-analytics

I know, I know, another question about Cocoapods that's BASICALLY the same...except not

I've been trying to follow [Segment's quickstart guide](https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/mobile/ios/quickstart/) in order to get their pod integrated with my project but have completely run up against a brick wall.  I am installing the pod they want me to, and calling `import Segment` in my `AppDelegate` so I can do the configuration, but all I am getting is `No such module 'Segment'`

Here's my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'

workspace 'Pace'

target 'Pace' do
  platform :ios, '12.0'
  project 'Pace.xcproject'
  
  pod 'Analytics', '~> 4.1'
  pod "SwiftPhoenixClient", '~> 1.0'
  pod 'MessageKit'
  pod 'TwilioVideo', '~> 3.7'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'SideMenu'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'OpenGraph'

end
```

I've tried every solution I have come across on SO and elsewhere, from checking `Find Implicit Dependencies` to marking the `Link Binary With Libraries` entry for the `Pods` as optional to...you get the idea.

And yes, I am 100% positive I am opening from the `.xcworkspace`

Help would, of course, be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution had to do with how Cocoapods handled Objective-C focused pods.

Namely, using `pod 'Analytics', '~> 4.1', :modular_headers => true` unblocked me.